# Why do Landsat 8 grayscales have a range of (0, 2^16-1) while the screen colors are (0, 2^8-1)?

Tags: raster, landsat, landsat-8, colormap

The grayscale levels in Landsat(0-65535) are more than that can be displayed on a standard display screen(0-255). The use of Landsat reflectance values must be more than just display purposes, which is my assumption(for drawing the graphs etc.). Because all the levels can't be shown using RGB color gradient.

Comment: Because they do not care about your screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the values have physical meaning - reflectance is a physical property, from which you can derive actual biological values such as chlorophyll content etc.
Since the values measured by the satellite can be used for other purposes than visualization, it makes good sense to make the measurements as accurate as possible. In order to store that information, more than 8-bit is required, which is why you see 16-bit imagery. If you go back to Landsat 5, the measurements were not accurate enough, and the storage limitations were such that 8-bits were the best choice, which is why images acquired by that satellite are provided as 8-bit grayscale.